# Find $x$ where $6 \equiv 7^{x} \pmod{71}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to find the value of $x$ such that

> $$6 \equiv 7^{x} \pmod{71}.$$

I don't know which formula would apply here, would Fermat's little theorem be applied here? or some other formula?

Comment: $7$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/(71\mathbb{Z})^*$ and this is just an instance of the discrete logarithm problem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm

Comment: i think it is $x=32$

Comment: a answer was already posted

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I did not understand the posted answer. I understand that discrete logarithm would be applied. But did not understand how you've done that? How did you get 32?

Answer (score 0):

Since $7^{70/2}\not\equiv 1\pmod{71}$, $7^{70/5}\not\equiv 1\pmod{71}$, $7^{70/7}\not\equiv 1\pmod{71}$, $7$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/(71\mathbb{Z})^*$ and this is just an instance of the [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). We may solve it through [baby step-giant step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step), for instance. Since $\sqrt{71}$ is roughly $8$, we may compute $7^0,7^1,\ldots, 7^7\pmod{71}$ and store these elements in a set $A$. Then we may compute $7^8,7^{16},\ldots,7^{64}\pmod{71}$, store these elements in a set $B$ and check when $ab\equiv 6\pmod{71}$ for some $a\in A, b\in B$. Actually $6$ is an element of $B$ and the solution is given by
$$ 7^{\color{red}{32}+70k}\equiv 6\pmod{71}.$$

Comment: I did not understand the answer. I understand that discrete logarithm would be applied. But did not understand how you've done that? How did you get 32?

Comment: @user5155835: we get $6$ when constructing $B$: $7^{32}\equiv 6$.

Comment: @user5155835: I already told you *how*. The set $B$ is the set of numbers of the form $7^{8k}\pmod{71}$, and $6$ is one of them. Please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step

Answer (score 0):

One checks $7$ is a generator of the cyclic group $\bigl(\mathbf Z/71\mathbf Z\bigr)^{\times}$, and $6$ has order $35$, hence $x$ is even coprime to $35$.

On the other hand, $7^6=2$, hence we only have to solve for $7^x=3$. Using the *fast exponentiation algorithm*, we test for even values of $x$ coprime to $35$: first $x\equiv 0 \bmod6$, then the other possible values, i.e. $x\in\{4,8,16,22,26,32,34,38,44,46, 52, 58,62,64,68\}$.

One eventually finds $7^{26}\equiv3\mod71$, so that
$$6=2\cdot 3=7^6\cdot7^{26}=7^{32}.$$